# "error C2228: left of '.ToString' must have class/struct/union"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

So I recently got Visual Studio 2012. I converted a Visual Studio 2010 solution to a Visual Studio 2012 project. It was working before I converted it.

I have this line of code:

```
this->Text = global::ProjectName + " (" + global::Type.ToString() + ") - Path Creator 2.0";
```

where global::Type is:

```
ref class global {
public:
    static Rct3PathType Type;
    ...
};
```

...and Rct3PathType is:

```
enum class Rct3PathType {
    Basic = 0x02060206,
    Extended = 0x05060506,
    Queue = 0x01070107
};
```

I get an error at compile time where ever I have called global::Type.ToString() saying "error C2228: left of '.ToString' must have class/struct/union". Considering this all compiled completely well BEFORE switching to Visual Studio 2012, I'm not sure what the issue is! :(

Also, when I try to run the last successful build (which was built with Visual Studio 2010), I get runtime error at startup saying "The program can't start becayse MSVCR100D.dll is missing from your computer." I know this probably doesn't relate to the issue at hand, but does anyone know why this may be happening as well?

Thanks for your help,
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"error C2228: left of '.ToString' must have class/struct/union": `enum class` is also the syntax for a C++11 enum. To make it a C++/CLI enum, give it an accessibility specifier, which is not allowed on a C++11 enum. In other words, `private enum class` or `public enum class` will change it from a C++11 enum to a C++/CLI enum. This wasn't a problem in VS2010 because it doesn't support C++11 enums.

"The program can't start because MSVCR100D.dll is missing from your computer.": VS2012 uses a different C runtime than VS2010. MSVCR100D is the Microsoft Visual C Runtime version 10.0, Debug version. This DLL is installed with VS2010, there is no other way to get it. If you have an old Release build, you can get the runtime redistributable from Microsoft ([x86](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) or [x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632)), and install that to make it run. (That will be MSVCR100.dll, no "D" at the end.)